# Left align div, then center align bottom text

Tags: html, css

[image]

Hello! So I'm using bootstrap 4.

I have 2 cols.

In the left one, I'd like to have a text **left-aligned** `Left aligned text`, and under it a centered `Centered text`

Same with the right aligned text.

How can I achieve a left-aligned and a right aligned text with center aligned text under them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned Bootstrap 4, this works:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="d-inline-block float-left">
      <div class="text-left">
        <h4>Left Aligned Text</h4>
        <span class="d-block text-center">center aligned text</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <div class="d-inline-block float-right">
      <div class="text-right">
        <h4>Right Aligned Text</h4>
        <span class="d-block text-center">center aligned text</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's how that should look:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, you’ve helped me really out !

Comment: Absolutely. My pleasure!